# getting previous week highs and lows in pandas dataframe using 30 min data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few set of days where the index is based on 30min data from monday to friday. There might some missing dates (Might be because of holidays). But i would like to find the highest from column high and lowest from column low for ever past week. Like i am calculating today so previous week high and low is marked in the yellow of attached image.

Tried using rolling , resampling but some how not working. Can any one help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut9Sx.png)

Comment: can you send your desired output to help you

Comment: also it might that max high in a week is different from min low on this week. In this case what do you do??

Comment: it would be best to post simple code to generate an example of your data , and what did you try so far

Comment: Please add a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)), i.e. code that produces the sample, and also include the expected output for the sample.

Answer (score 1):

You really should add sample data to your question (by that I mean a piece of code/text that can easily be used to create a dataframe for illustrating how the proposed solution works).

Here's a suggestion. With `df` your dataframe, and column `datatime` with datetimes (and not strings):

```
df["week"] = (
    df["datetime"].dt.isocalendar().year.astype(str)
    + df["datetime"].dt.isocalendar().week.astype(str)
)
mask = df["high"] == df.groupby("week")["high"].transform("max")
df = df.merge(
    df[mask].rename(columns={"low": "high_low"})
            .groupby("week").agg({"high_low": "min"}).shift(),
    on="week", how="left"
).drop(columns="week")
```

- Add a `week` column to `df` (year + week) for grouping along weeks.
- Extract the rows with the weekly maximum `high`s by `mask` (there could be more than one for a week).
- Build a corresponding dataframe with the weekly minimum of the `low`s corresponding to the weekly maximum `high`s (column named `high_low`), `shift` it once to get the value from the previous week, and [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it to `df`.

If column `datetime` doesn't contain datetimes:

```
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, the solution should be

1. get the week number from the date
2. groupby the week number and fetch the max and min number.
3. groupby the week fetch max date to get max/last date for a week
4. now merge all the dataframes into one based on date key
5. Once the steps are done, you could do any formatting as required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).